# sending file to backend angular full stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, amazon-s3

I am using yeoman angular fullstack and im trying to do a simple file upload. I read the file from a form and i get it into the front end just fine

```
this.$scope.add = function() {

    var f = document.getElementById('resume').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.result);
        Auth.saveResume({
          data: e.target.result,
          name:theFile.name
        });
      };
    })(f);

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);      
  }
```

in auth.services.ts i have

```
saveResume(resume, callback?: Function) {
  console.log(User)
  return User.saveResume({ id: currentUser._id }, {resume},
    function() {
      console.log('auth.service in function');
      console.log('currentUser._id: ' + currentUser._id);
      return safeCb(callback)(null);
    },
    function(err) {
      return safeCb(callback)(err);
    }).$promise;
},
```

it successfully makes it into my back end controller

```
router.put('/:id/resume', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.saveResume);
```

where i have a saveResume function

```
export function saveResume(req, res){

    console.log(typeof req.body.resume.data);
    console.log(typeof req.body.resume.name);

}
```

In the save resume function when i access the "name" parameter it is correct and is of type string. However when i access "data" i just get an object. I would like data to be either a file or buffer so i can upload it to s3.

My only guess for why its an object instead of an ArrayBuffer is that i think node doesnt support javascript ArrayBuffers, blobs, or files. How do i get the file in the backend in some form that s3 will accept? ie file, blob, or buffer

Comment: Are you using express on the server side? Shouldn't the file data be in a special property, something like req.file (Meaning your client service should properly setup up the request)? Or, you encode it in base64 and send it as body content, then decode it on the server side.

Comment: im using express. Are there any good resources to learn how to go about creating a special property to put the file in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bubblez suggest i encoded it to base 64 like so

```
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var base64;
     // Onload of file read the file content
     fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        // Print data in console
        console.log(base64);
        Auth.saveResume(f.name, base64);
      };
    // Convert data to base64
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
```

i also changed auth so that it takes two separate parameters

```
saveResume(name, data, callback?: Function) {
  console.log(User)
  return User.saveResume({ id: currentUser._id }, {name, data},
    function() {
      console.log('auth.service in function');
      console.log('currentUser._id: ' + currentUser._id);
      return safeCb(callback)(null);
    },
    function(err) {
      return safeCb(callback)(err);
    }).$promise;
},
```

i then decode from base 64

```
export function saveResume(req, res){
    var base64String = req.body.data.split(';base64,').pop();
    console.log(base64String);
    var buf = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64').toString('utf');
    uploadParams.Body = buf;
}
```

and this works!